# Where can we read/find the "Naqsh e Rajab" inscription of the Magian Priest Kartir?

Tags: religion, persia, religious-history, zoroastrianism

In the Encyclopaedia Iranica entry on the Arda Wiraz, it mentions:

> ...The narrative of Wīrāz is not unique. Parallels are found in more precisely dated sources—the legend of Zoroaster recorded in Dēnkard 7 and the monumental inscriptions of the 3rd-century priest, Kirdīr (q.v.).
>
> **[ Encyclopaedia Iranica: Arda Wiraz ]**

I am trying to read the narrative of the Arda Wiraz at its earliest known source.

I could not find this inscription by googling except that in Wikipedia it says:

> Kartir's inscription contains 31 lines in Middle Persian and in the left side of it, a portrait of Kartir himself is incised. The text introduces Kartir and **briefly describes his ascent (Kardegān).**

Which is promising. Hopefully someone here can tell me where I can read the Naqsh e Rajab inscriptions of the Magian priest, Kartir.

High quality photos of the original inscription from a reliable source, or a reliable transcription are ideal, but beggars can't be choosers.

Comment: See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naqsh-e_Rajab

Comment: And some (not very high-res) images and a modern translation at https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Kartir%27s_inscription_at_Naqsh-e_Rajab

Comment: thanks so much, as you said the actual images of the rock inscription are pretty low res and/or shadowy  so i cant actually read anything  ._.  The metal plate's modern translation is very readable and I can make do with that for now but the ideal is high resolution images of the inscription.  And do you know how i can find out who produced that translation ? on wikimedia it says it is in the inscription garden of Tehran (if that helps)

Comment: @Jan Can you confirm if that “modern translation” is complete and omits nothing of the actual inscription?

Comment: @Hisham No, I am just a random guy who uses google. I can confirm that the first sentence of that farsi text is written in first person singular.

Comment: For some bibliography, see https://sites.uci.edu/sasanika/kartir-inscription-naqs-e-rajab-knrb/ (but note that some of these entries may be about other inscriptions by Kartir)